# Getting Error "Image reader can not be created from -vec generated/vectors/positives.vec and -bg generated/negatives.txt."

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv, haar-classifier

I was working on my research and I got this error as the title

`Image reader can not be created from -vec generated/vectors/positives.vec and -bg generated/negatives.txt.`

when I was trying to train a Haar Cascade for testing.

Here's the full code:

https://hastebin.com/juyewezobo.lua

And here's the output (You can scroll to the bottom) :

https://hastebin.com/aziwibifey.yaml

Here's the file tree:

https://hastebin.com/cirusapiva.typescript

This is pretty much killing me, so please help me if you know how to fix this.

Thank you.